# how to leave the field filled with fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem : when a customer enters his shipping and billing informations in my form, the fields of the address model lose all information if the page is reloaded.
It works with the other fields, like email, that are included directly in the order model. How could I leave the fields filled after reloading ?

Here's my new.html.erb file :

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
  <ul>
   <% @order.errors.each_with_index do |msg, i| %>
    <li><%= msg[1] %></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
 <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "email" %>
 <%= f.fields_for :shipping_address_attributes do |sa| %> 
  <%= sa.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "Firstname" %>  
  <%= sa.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Name", autocomplete: true %>
  <%= sa.text_field :address1, placeholder: "Address", autocomplete: true %>
  #etc.
 <% end %>
 <p><%= f.submit 'Next step' %></p>
<% end %>
```

My models :

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address"
 belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address"
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, reject_if: :bill_to_shipping_address    

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :billing_addresses, :class_name => "Order", :foreign_key => "billing_address_id", dependent: :nullify
  has_many :shipping_addresses, :class_name => "Order", :foreign_key => "shipping_address_id", dependent: :nullify
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :address1, :city, :country, :phone, :postal
```

and my order_controller.rb:

```
def new
 @user = current_user
 @order_items = current_order.order_items
 @order = current_order
 @amount = @order.subtotal
end

def update
@order_items = current_order.order_items
@order = current_order
  if @order.update(order_params)
    redirect_to recapitulatif_de_la_commande_path
  else
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
end
```

EDIT

Maybe the error is due to the fact that the order is not linked to any shipping address before the update action ? It works only if address model validate the presence of each attributes.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you including the shipping address attributes in permitted params?

Comment: yes : " :shipping_address_attributes => [:first_name, :country,etc. "